# Android 26 Unable to start receiver com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

Hi

I got an error message when i send a push message to my game in Android Oreo.
The game works well for all previous version of Android Oreo.
It only happens in Android Oreo.
I have searched many answers in this forum.
Some people say that i have to use FCM instead of GCM.
But I can't change my old Eclipse project to Android Studio
because of many risks.
I use gcm.jar library.
Please help me & thanks in advance!

**Logcat**

```
        FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=com.example.test cmp=com.example.test/.GCMIntentService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{7cd2325 u0a379 RCVR idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1672)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)    
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=com.example.test cmp=com.example.test/.GCMIntentService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{7cd2325 u0a379 RCVR idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1518)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1474)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:649)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:649)
        at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.runIntentInService(GCMBaseIntentService.java:282)
        at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(GCMBroadcastReceiver.java:55)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3187)
```

Comment: *I have searched many answers in this forum.* - you didn't search very well. I just copied your error and found the exact same question

Comment: many people tell me to refer to the manual of 'backround execution limits'. or they say that i have to use 'startForegroundService' instead of 'startService'. but i can't understand what to do. i just use '<service android:name="com.example.test.GCMIntentService" />' in AndroidManifest.xml file. and i use 'public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService { ... }'. that's all. it works well for all version of android except android oreo. please give me an example code.

Comment: @KiSeokKim Have you got the example ?

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Android O.

> The startService() method now throws an IllegalStateException if an app targeting Android 8.0 tries to use that method in a situation when it isn't permitted to create background services.

By default, these restrictions only apply to apps that target O,but if  user enable these restrictions for a particular app, then app will treated as same.
 For more info on topic read **Background execution limits** section [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html).

Comment: many people tell me to refer to the manual of 'backround execution limits'. or they say that i have to use 'startForegroundService' instead of 'startService'. but i can't understand what to do. i just use '<service android:name="com.example.test.GCMIntentService" />' in AndroidManifest.xml file. and i use 'public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService { ... }'. that's all. it works well for all version of android except android oreo. please give me an example code.

Comment: @KiSeokKim have you got the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

From API 26 onwords you won't be allow to start or destroy services in background.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html

for more detail read here.

There are so much limitations in API 26 for battery optimizations and some security reasons.

Comment: many people tell me to refer to the manual of 'backround execution limits'. or they say that i have to use 'startForegroundService' instead of 'startService'. but i can't understand what to do. i just use '<service android:name="com.example.test.GCMIntentService" />' in AndroidManifest.xml file. and i use 'public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService { ... }'. that's all. it works well for all version of android except android oreo. please give me an example code.